# Graphql return None when no values are found

Tags: graphql

I have the following query:

```
    """  query Odds($id: ID!) {
            odds(id: $id) {
                oddsMarkets {
                    oddsOptions {
                        ... on OddsToWin {
                            odds
                        }
                        ... on OddsFinishes {
                            odds
                        }
                        ... on OddsCutsPlayers {
                            odds
                        }
                        ... on OddsLeadersPlayers {
                            odds
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
   """
```

I was wondering if its possible to return all the desired values even if they are non-existent (return them as `None`). At the moment I am getting the following dictionary returned:

```
{
  'odds': {
    'oddsMarkets': [
      {
        'oddsOptions': [
          {
            'odds': '+1200'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see `+1200` is located in a list. By doing research I know that this value corresponds to `OddsToWin`. But if I don't know this in advance, how do I know if `odds` represents the odds of winning, finishing, cutting or becoming the leader?
Let's say the server only returns the `odds` from `OddsLeadersPlayers`. It will also show up
in `oddsOptions[0]` right?

Is it possible to retrieve all odds values even if they are null / None or is there another way to make it more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is to use aliases:

```
query Odds($id: ID!) {
  odds(id: $id) {
    oddsMarkets {
      oddsOptions {
        ... on OddsToWin {
          odds2w:odds
        }
        ... on OddsFinishes {
          oddsF:odds
        }
        ... on OddsCutsPlayers {
          oddsCP:odds
        }
        ... on OddsLeadersPlayers {
          oddsLP:odds
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that unlike in JS, the alias name comes *before* the original name.

Comment: Thanks. Using your suggestion; Is it also possible to return a dictionary looking as follows: 

'odds = {"OddsToWin": odds2w,
        "OddsFinishes": oddsF,
        "OddsCutsPlayers": oddsCPm
        "oddsLeadersPlayers": oddsLP
        }'. 
Maybe using a custom class or something?

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for with this comment. You can't easily get rid of those two middle layers since they are set in the schema on the server.